# Implement function to move jQuery elements conserving events handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I can conserve event handlers when manipulating an element with jQuery using:

```
$element.clone(true)
```

How would I implement a function like this:

```
$element.withHandlers().appendTo('#my-div')
```

That would append `$element` to `#my-div` copying its event handlers?

Comment: As long as you don't call `$element.remove();` you can, in fact, call `append`, `insertBefore`, etc. anytime; the events and data will follow every time. FYI, use `$element.detach();` instead of `remove` if you want to disconnect it from the DOM and keep it's events and data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't call $element.remove(); you can, in fact, call append, insertBefore, etc. anytime; the events and data will follow every time. FYI, use $element.detach(); instead of remove if you want to disconnect it from the DOM and keep it's events and data. – Yanick Rochon

Answer (score 3):

```
.clone( [withDataAndEvents] [, deepWithDataAndEvents] )
```

```
$element.clone(true, true).appendTo('#my-div')
```

Comment: But this would modify the behaviour of appendTo, because would not move the element, isn't it?

Comment: @juanpastas No, `clone` returns a jQuery object,

Comment: @juanpastas, `clone` returns a jQuery object that is **not** attached to the DOM, and which is a copy of the source element (attached or not).

Comment: I see, but if I have $element in the document I would have then to remove it with `remove`, I think

Comment: @juanpastas Do you want to move the element or clone it and then append it? If you want to clone the element, use clone, otherwise you can append the element without cloning it.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I understand now I don't need to clone to move the element with its event handlers